# PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException (Array to string conversion) Yii

Tags: php, yii2

My data is succesfully entering into database. But, not redirecting to register.php page after inserting.

Showing Notice like:

> **PHP Notice** – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Array to string conversion

But, I Noticed that as soon i'm replacing this line `return $this->refresh($post);` from SiteController.php, All working fine.

So, why this `refresh($post)` not working.. as it was working fine in other page.

I'm not getting how to resolve this issue. I need help. Please help me.

**register.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'register-form']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'fname')->textInput()->label('First Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'lname')->textInput()->label('Last Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput()->label('Email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->label('Password') ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'register-button' ]) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**SiteController.php (Controller)**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionRegister()
        {
        $model = new RegisterForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $post = Yii::$app->request->post('RegisterForm');
    
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO members SET FirstName=:fname, LastName=:lname, EmailID=:email, Password=:password",
                        array(':fname' => $post['fname'],':lname'=>$post['lname'],':email'=>$post['email'],':password'=>$post['password']))->execute();
            
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('registerFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh($post);
        }
        return $this->render('register', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
        }
}
```

**RegisterForm.php (model)**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;


class RegisterForm extends Model
{
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $email;
    public $password;

    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fname','lname', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
        ];
    }

   
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) 
    {
        /*
                $form= new Form();
        $form->name=$this->name;
        $form->email=$this->email;
        $form->passowrd=$this->passowrd;
        $form->save();
        */
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Here is Print screen of error coming.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily see on the error screen you have shown us that `$anchor` being sent to the method named `refresh()` is an array, and you are trying to concatenate it as if it was a string. That is it.

Since the documentation on that screen says `$anchor` is expected to be a string in that method, the only reason left is the fact that you are sending it incorrect data.

Comment: So, what changes i need  to do Mr Hanky.

Comment: Send it a string which you want to use as anchor to your redirect url. If there is none then just dont send anything to it, instead of `$post`.

Comment: Yeah. Working. Thanks Mr Hanky.